# Can't use font after MiKTeX update

Tags: fonts, miktex2.9, miktex-update

I made isocpeur.ttf font ([my early subject](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/344392/set-sffamily-if-needed-font-is-not-installed)) able to use in LaTeX ([MiKTeXfont.zip](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1XACL7nGiUIoNFbebtShyxhwK9irINyET/view?usp=sharing)) long time ago, and used it successful until yesterday. Didn't update my MiKTeX since 2019 so decided to renew it.

After update I can't compile even simpliest document ([basic.zip](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1AWiFITR4Dnj4D58EsnWLInQWfmr1p3zl/view?usp=sharing)) because of this:
[image]

What changed since I update my MiKTeX and how can I fix it?

---

Small complete example

```
\documentclass{extreport}

\begin{document}
\fontfamily{iso}
\selectfont
This is a test.
\end{document}
```

---

Log file

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.24 (MiKTeX 21.12.10) 
(preloaded format=pdflatex 2022.1.26)  26 JAN 2022 14:47
entering extended mode
restricted \write18 enabled.
%&-line parsing enabled.
**./bdr.tex
(bdr.tex
LaTeX2e <2021-11-15> patch level 1
L3 programming layer <2022-01-21>
(C:\Users\user9\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 
2.9\tex/latex/extsizes\extreport.cls
Document Class: extreport 1996/10/08 v1.0 Non Standard LaTeX document 
class
(C:\Users\user9\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 
2.9\tex/latex/base\size10.clo
File: size10.clo 2021/10/04 v1.4n Standard LaTeX file (size option)
)
(C:\Users\user9\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 
2.9\tex/latex/base\exscale.sty
Package: exscale 2018/09/24 v2.1i Standard LaTeX package exscale
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring symbol font `largesymbols' on input line 
57.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `largesymbols' in version 
`normal'
(Font)                  OMX/cmex/m/n --> OMX/cmex/m/n on input line 57.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `largesymbols' in version 
`bold'
(Font)                  OMX/cmex/m/n --> OMX/cmex/m/n on input line 57.
\big@size=\dimen138
)
\c@part=\count185
\c@chapter=\count186
\c@section=\count187
\c@subsection=\count188
\c@subsubsection=\count189
\c@paragraph=\count190
\c@subparagraph=\count191
\c@figure=\count192
\c@table=\count193
\abovecaptionskip=\skip47
\belowcaptionskip=\skip48
\bibindent=\dimen139
)
(C:\Users\user9\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 
2.9\tex/latex/l3backend\l3backend
-pdftex.def
File: l3backend-pdftex.def 2022-01-12 L3 backend support: PDF output 
(pdfTeX)
\l__color_backend_stack_int=\count194
\l__pdf_internal_box=\box50
)
No file bdr.aux.
\openout1 = `bdr.aux'.

LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OML/cmm/m/it on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMS/cmsy/m/n on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OT1/cmr/m/n on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for T1/cmr/m/n on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for TS1/cmr/m/n on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMX/cmex/m/n on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for U/cmr/m/n on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    Trying to load font information for OT1+iso on input 
line 5
.
(C:/Users/user9/MiKTeX ttfonts\tex/latex/microsoft/isocpeur\ot1iso.fd
File: ot1iso.fd 2016/11/13 Fontinst v1.933 font definitions for OT1/iso.
)
! Font OT1/iso/m/n/10=isor7t at 10.0pt not loadable: Metric (TFM) file 
not found.
<to be read again> 
                   relax 
l.5 \selectfont
               
? 
Missing character: There is no T in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no h in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no i in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no s in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no i in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no s in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no a in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no t in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no e in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no s in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no t in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no . in font nullfont!
[1

{C:/Users/user9/AppData/Local/MiKTeX/2.9/fonts/map/pdftex/pdftex.map}]
(bdr.aux) ) 
Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
482 strings out of 478555
10734 string characters out of 2840913
296675 words of memory out of 3000000
18749 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+600000
469259 words of font info for 28 fonts, out of 8000000 for 9000
1141 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
41i,5n,48p,184b,109s stack positions out of 
5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,80000s
<C:/Users/user9/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX 2.9/fonts/type1/public
/amsfonts/cm/cmr10.pfb>
Output written on bdr.pdf (1 page, 9261 bytes).
PDF statistics:
11 PDF objects out of 1000 (max. 8388607)
0 named destinations out of 1000 (max. 500000)
1 words of extra memory for PDF output out of 10000 (max. 10000000)
```

---

Small complete example with `\pdfmapfile{}`

```
\documentclass{extreport}

\begin{document}
\pdfmapfile{=isocpeur.map}
\fontencoding{T1}
\fontfamily{iso}
\selectfont
This is a test.
\end{document}
```

---

Log file

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.24 (MiKTeX 21.12.10) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2022.1.26)  26 JAN 2022 17:03
entering extended mode
 restricted \write18 enabled.
 %&-line parsing enabled.
**./bdr.tex
(bdr.tex
LaTeX2e <2021-11-15> patch level 1
L3 programming layer <2022-01-21>
(C:\Users\user9\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/extsizes\extreport.
cls
Document Class: extreport 1996/10/08 v1.0 Non Standard LaTeX document class
(C:\Users\user9\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/base\size10.clo
File: size10.clo 2021/10/04 v1.4n Standard LaTeX file (size option)
)
(C:\Users\user9\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/base\exscale.sty
Package: exscale 2018/09/24 v2.1i Standard LaTeX package exscale
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring symbol font `largesymbols' on input line 57.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `largesymbols' in version `normal'
(Font)                  OMX/cmex/m/n --> OMX/cmex/m/n on input line 57.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `largesymbols' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OMX/cmex/m/n --> OMX/cmex/m/n on input line 57.
\big@size=\dimen138
)
\c@part=\count185
\c@chapter=\count186
\c@section=\count187
\c@subsection=\count188
\c@subsubsection=\count189
\c@paragraph=\count190
\c@subparagraph=\count191
\c@figure=\count192
\c@table=\count193
\abovecaptionskip=\skip47
\belowcaptionskip=\skip48
\bibindent=\dimen139
)
(C:\Users\user9\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/l3backend\l3backend
-pdftex.def
File: l3backend-pdftex.def 2022-01-12 L3 backend support: PDF output (pdfTeX)
\l__color_backend_stack_int=\count194
\l__pdf_internal_box=\box50
)
No file bdr.aux.
\openout1 = `bdr.aux'.

LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OML/cmm/m/it on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMS/cmsy/m/n on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OT1/cmr/m/n on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for T1/cmr/m/n on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for TS1/cmr/m/n on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMX/cmex/m/n on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for U/cmr/m/n on input line 3.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 3.
{C:/Users/user9/AppData/Local/MiKTeX/2.9/fonts/map/pdftex/pdftex.map}

pdfTeX warning: pdflatex (file isocpeur.map): cannot open font map file
LaTeX Font Info:    Trying to load font information for T1+iso on input line 7.

(C:/Users/user9/MiKTeX ttfonts\tex/latex/microsoft/isocpeur\t1iso.fd
File: t1iso.fd 2016/11/13 Fontinst v1.933 font definitions for T1/iso.
) [1

]
(bdr.aux) ) 
Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
 485 strings out of 478555
 10755 string characters out of 2840913
 296675 words of memory out of 3000000
 18749 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+600000
 469915 words of font info for 30 fonts, out of 8000000 for 9000
 1141 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
 41i,5n,48p,184b,123s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,80000s

!pdfTeX error: pdflatex (file isor8r): Font isor8r at 600 not found
 ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
```

Comment: run in the miktex console (if in doubt in user mode) the task "refresh font map files"

Comment: @Ulrike Fischer did it and even more than once. Doesn't work for me.

Comment: does it work if you add `\pdfmapfile{=isocpeur.map}` to your document?

Comment: @Ulrike Fischer added this command to preamble and added to document body - still doesn't work in any case.

Comment: Show a small complete example and the log file. The I can try and  compare with my system.

Comment: Added small complete example with log to my question post. In this case I got .pdf file but it ampty.

Comment: Try with \fontencoding{T1}, the OT1 support looks incomplete.

Comment: `\font encoding{T1}` use causes following issue:
`!pdfTeX error: pdflatex (file isor8r): Font isor8r at 600 not found`
 `==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!`

Comment: Well and now add the \pdfmapfile line. And if this still errors show the log-file.

Comment: Added `\pdfmapfile{}` and  log to example.

Comment: Well the log says `pdfTeX warning: pdflatex (file isocpeur.map): cannot open font map file`. I think that you didn't correctly install your texmf with the font. Did you attach the root of the unpacked miktexfont.zip in the miktex console as a new root?

Comment: I've been using this font long time before. It was installed to separate folder prescribed as TEXMF root directory. All were fine until recent update. After this I tried to fix it with refreshing file names database and font map files... Nothing. I copied all font files to true root directory according to tree structure and tried refresh again... Nothing. I see that the MiKTeX can't found files but I don't know why.

Comment: move the map file from dvips/config into fonts/map/dvips. Refresh everything then it should work.

Comment: It works at last! Thank you! I still don't understand what exactly went wrong. Can you point me where can I read about this issue for future eventual updates?

Comment: well the map was in the wrong place. I don't know (remember) if it worked at some time if it was in the dvips folder, but now it should be in some subfolder of fonts/map.  That is more logical for a map that it also used by pdflatex.

Comment: Or better write answer with your last two comments so I can mark it as solved. In future I or someone can see this nonobvious decision.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `zip` the map file `isocpeur.map` is in the folder `dvips\config`. That is the wrong folder in a current TeX system. `map` files should be in a subfolder of  `fonts\map`. E.g. in `fonts\map\dvips`.